# how to automate using selenium without inspect elements option

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath-2.0

I need to automate web based application which i am currently accessing through citrix due to some reason client have disabled  inspect element and other option in their machine is there any way to automate it through selenium.

Comment: Can you view Page Source?

Comment: nope we can see page source

Comment: do you mean can or can't?

Comment: have you tried F12 in your browser.

Comment: no we can not see page source and f12 also didnt work